# Generate a sequence of real numbers using a recursive formula

Tags: matlab, random

I have two tasks to do in Matlab related with a pseudo-random number generator.
1. Generate a sawtooth wave, but I can not use a matlab sawtooth function.
2. Generate a sequence of real numbers using a recursive formula.

[image: There is my problem]

I've done a first task, and I think this is good:

```
size = 1000;
z = 3; %number of teeth
x = 0:1/size:1;
f = mod (x*z,1);
plot(x,f)
grid
```

[image: There is a result:]

But I don't know how to do the second task. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is homework. We dont do homework for other people. Show you attempt

Comment: In your recursive function, you should have a line that look like: `x = [rand(1), your_function(n-1)]` where `n` is the input of your function and `x` the output. Just add an `if` `else` condition to stop calling `your_function` when `n==1` (or whatever you want).